# Confused about boundaries of %d and %ld and %lld and %u in C

Tags: c

Look at following code compiled in visual studio 2012.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    long long end1 = 12345678908642;

    long end2 = 65537;

    printf("end1 = %lld and %u\n" , end1 , end1); // line a

    printf("end2 = %d and %ld and %u\n" , end2 , end2 , end2); // line b

    printf("end2 = %d and %ld and %lld and %u\n" , end2 , end2 , end2 , end2); // line c

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Q1:   I thought in line a, the two numbers %lld and %u show are the same while they are not, but why in line b, %u shows the right number?

Q2:    In line c, %lld and %u shows the wrong number, why?  I thought they should be the same like %d and %ld.

I am so confused .

Comment: Wrong format specifiers trigger undefined behaviour. That's all.

Comment: Assuming that a `long long` is 64 bits and a `long` 32 bits, I'd assume that the `printf` call on line 'a' simply takes the first 32 bits of the second `end1` argument, interpreting them as an unsigned int. So yeah, don't use mismatching format specifiers.

Comment: RTFM. There are enough questions about wrong format specifiers. What is the problem just reading the info page for `printf`?

Answer (score 4):

The conversion specifiers (like %u) *must* match the type of the corresponding value given as argument.

printf uses a variable parameter list. After integer promotion, the actual arguments are pushed on the function stack, but the offsets of each individual actual argument are not known to the callee (printf); those offsets are instead reconstructed from the format string.

Thus, the strange behavior you see can be explained if you consider all your actual arguments to be first concatenated by the caller and read by the callee (printf) with different offsets (according to the conversion specifiers, which do not match the actual arguments).

Answer (score 4):

This triggers `undefined behavior`, as stated before, because you do not use the good format string.

If you want an in depth analysis of what's happening (again, it's UB, so what you see here might change on another computer/compier/...), here it is:

From what happens, I assume that you're working on a 32bit machine, in which `sizeof long == sizeof int == 4`. In this case, `%d` and `%ld` have the same behavior (read 4 bytes from variadic arguments and print them as a signed integer), while `%lld` will read 8 bytes. Same goes for `%u` and variants, with unsigned integer values.

That explains the first line : the `%u` prints only half the bytes of `end1` (so the value is ... bad).

For the second line, as your number in `end2` is small enough to fit either in a signed or an unsigned `long`, then printing with `%u` produces the same result as printing with `%d`, which in turn produces the same result as `%ld`.

For the third line, the `%d` and `%ld` works, then the `%lld` reads 8 bytes from the arguments (so it reads the two remaining `end2`) and prints something that you consider "wrong". Then the last `%u` will read 4 bytes after the last argument (somewhere on the stack), and then the value is "garbage" for you.

Hope this helps ;).

Note: Remember that the most important thing is "Using a wrong format string leads to `undefined behaviour`", which means that your code could produce completely different output on another compiler/computer/... !